# i have to search from the database "employee details" for the employee name using parameterised

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview(gridview1) which where I have initially displayed my database using sqlDataSource(ID:sqlDataSource1). I have provided a search button to the user from where he can search for an employee by typing his name. On clicking on that button, the gridview should display only the matching results.

this is the function I have performed on button click. Is there any command that I am missing out?
the error shown is: Must declare the scalar variable "@TextBoxSearchParameter".

TextBoxSearch is the ID of a textBox.
EmployeeDetails is  a database that has employeeID and the EmployeeName

```
 protected void ButtonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "select * from EmployeeDetails where 
 EmployeeName like @TextBoxSearchParameter";
            SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("@TextBoxSearchParameter", 
 TextBoxSearch.Text + "%");
 GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

It should display the record of all the employees starting with the name as entered by the user on the gridview1.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
protected void ButtonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "select * from EmployeeDetails where 
 EmployeeName like @TextBoxSearchParameter %";
            SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.AddWithValue("@TextBoxSearchParameter", 
 TextBoxSearch.Text);
 GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 protected void ButtonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "select * from EmployeeDetails where  EmployeeName like '%@TextBoxSearchParameter%'"; //query modified
      SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("@TextBoxSearchParameter",  TextBoxSearch.Text); // modified the  around TextBoxSearch.Text
      GridView1.DataBind();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "select * from EmployeeDetails where EmployeeName like '% @TextBoxSearchParameter %' ";
 SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("@TextBoxSearchParameter", 
 TextBoxSearch.Text);
```